# How can I install Sublime Text on QNX?

Tags: linux, text-editors

How can I install Sublime Text 2 on a Linux distribution I am using called QNX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QNX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QNX) is not a Linux distribution.  It's not even really much of a Unix.

Given that [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) does not come in a version for QNX, and given that the source code doesn't seem to be available for download (it's a commercial product), chances are that you aren't going to be able to make it work on QNX without the assistance of the authors.

Comment: Thanks, this is unfortunate, do you know of any good ide programs that will work with QNX?

Comment: I don't know of any IDEs that run *on* QNX.  Keep in mind that QNX has not been historically intended as a desktop operating system.  QNX is intended for, say, nuclear power plants, medical devices and ATMs.  As such, when most people think of "QNX IDE", they're thinking about IDEs for software *targeting* QNX, not running on it.  You might have luck running vim, which [can have IDE features grafted on](http://haridas.in/vim-as-your-ide.html)...

Comment: Yeah i am having some trouble installing VIM, i will keep trying though.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: you can't. QNX is a proprietary OS and not compatible with Linux; besides, Sublime Text  is closed-source, if the developers haven't released a version for a specific platform, it won't work.